# Problemas instalacion de gulp

Tags: gulp

al instalar gulp, me devuelve esto:

> iMac-de-Luis:~ luisquesadaromero$ sudo npm install -g gulp
>
> npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2
>   or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
>
> npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2
>   or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
>
> npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before
>   will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to
>   graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to
>   find it in the tree.
>
> npm WARN gentlyRm not removing /Users/luisquesadaromero/.npm-global
>
> /bin/gulp as it wasn't installed by
>   /Users/luisquesadaromero/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/gulp
>
> /Users/luisquesadaromero/.npm-global/bin/gulp ->
>   /Users/luisquesadaromero/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
>
> /Users/luisquesadaromero/.npm-global/lib └── gulp@3.9.1

Comment: Parece que tienes que actualizar `minimatch`

Comment: Y cual problema tienes? Lo mensaje son solos **advertencias**...

Comment: Corre esto en tu consola. sudo npm install -g minimatch@3.0.2 si no te funciona ejecuta este otro npm install -g npm, el comando básicamente lo que hará es actualizar el npm

Comment: gracias por contestar, el problema es que cuando solicito version de gulp me devuelve:
iMac-de-Luis:~ luisquesadaromero$ gulp -v

-bash: gulp: command not found

Soy muy novato, perdonar, pero eso quiere decir que no esta instalado?